# Comment réduire une phrase à sa forme canonique?

Tags: sens, terminologie

Sans aborder les aspects philosophiques qui en découlent, je souhaite connaître la méthode à utiliser sur la phrase suivante, de manière à pouvoir réduire sa longueur à sa forme la plus canonique, tout en conservant l'entier de son sens ?

> Il est des circonstances dans la vie où l'homme, quel qu'intelligent qu'il soit, n'en obtempère pas moins à des raisons qui, bien qu'aléatoires, n'en sont pas moins intrinsèques et absolues, et réciproquement."

Prenons l'exemple d'une autre phrase,

> Le merveilleux ciel bleu d'où jaillissent de jaunes rayons aux reflets mordorés permettant à cet étourneau sauvage de se réchauffer.

La première étape nécessaire me semble être l'élimination des adjectifs inutiles et des éléments de liaison et de rythme.

> Le ciel bleu d'où jaillissent des rayons qui permettent à cet étourneau de se réchauffer.

Le terme rayon s'applique ici, par convention, aux rayons du soleil. L'information du ciel bleu n'était ici que l'indice d'un ciel dégagé et d'un soleil bien visible. Par conséquent, on peut alors écrire :

> Les rayons de soleil permettent à cet étourneau de se réchauffer.

Or, nous savons que, le consensus s'accorde à dire que les rayons du soleil concernent la partie visible du spectre, laquelle n'englobe pas les infrarouges qui contribue au réchauffement de l'étourneau. Aussi, il est encore possible de simplifier la phrase.

> La chaleur du soleil permet à cet étourneau de se réchauffer.

Je pense que le terme chaleur n'est ici pas nécessaire, nous comprenons aisément le sens de la phase.

> Le soleil permet à cet étourneau de se réchauffer.

Et donc :

> Le soleil réchauffe cet étourneau.

Ceci me semble être la forme canonique de la phrase initiale.

Qu'en est-il de ma première phrase ? Est-ce que mon raisonnement est cohérent ?

Comment: "Il est des circonstances dans la vie" = "parfois" , mais on y perd un peu de sens...

Comment: Concernant la phrase donnée en exemple, je remarque qu'elle est incomplète (le verbe est dans une subordonnée) et que le sujet change au cours de la réflexion : d'abord le ciel, il devient le soleil et ce qui était proposition subordonnée devient principale.

Comment: Est-ce que quelqu'un sait quelle est la source de la première phrase d'exemple ? On trouve plein de versions différentes de cette phrase sur Internet mais je ne trouve aucune mention de la source originale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cela ressemble beaucoup à une phrase générée par *[un robot de ce genre](http://romainvaleri.online.fr/)*, phrase qui a donc un sens hasardeux, en *contraction de texte*, cela pourrait donner, en neuf mots  :

> Parfois l'homme obtempère aux aléatoires raisons intrinsèques, absolues.

... de *[l'Oulipo](http://oulipo.net/)* aux mystères des présentations insondables, qui augmentent de trois mots ces deux fiers alexandrins :

> Aléatoires raisons absolues, intrinsèques,
>   Ô homme, parfois ou non, obtempère aussi sec !

---

L'option robot semble se confirmer : un humain aurait supprimé le premier article et 'montré' les rayons :

> Merveilleux ciel bleu d'où jaillissent ces jaunes rayons aux reflets mordorés qui permettent à cet étourneau sauvage de se réchauffer.

Ce qui pourrait donner, en conservant les verbes d'action, et en gardant l'emphase :

> Ces jaillissants rais célestes  réchauffent l'étourneau.

... Ces jaillissants rais (qui ne peuvent être que solaires puisqu'ils sont célestes, et donc par nature jaune et or [mordoré]) célestes (l'immense majorité des ciels sont bleus s'il y a du soleil et donc des rayons) 
 réchauffent  (*permettent le réchauffement* ne fonctionne pas)  l'(le *ce* n'apporte rien puisque la phrase ne parle que d'un seul volatile) étourneau (qui est par nature sauvage).

---

N.B. : Le code civil, et les lois en général, sont des exemples parfaits de contraction de texte.

Comment: Je vote +1 pour le robot générateur !

Comment: J'ai complété ma réponse avec le problème de *contraction de texte* de l'étourneau ; le plus difficile dans cet exercice est de conserver "l'esprit" de l'original, sa "couleur". Vous avez fait une traduction en introduisant le mot *soleil* et en oblitérant la qualité de son environnement lumineux.

Comment: C'est une remarque très pertinente.

Answer (score 2):

Le plus court que je puisse obtenir sans perte de sens :

> L'homme obtempère ou non à des raisons intrinsèques et absolues.

Comment: J'ai l'impression que cette phrase ne transmet aucune information. C'est comme de dire que "tout homme a, ou non, les yeux bleus" : c'est vrai, mais c'est tout. Je remplacerais simplement "ou non" par "parfois" (ou "dans certaines circonstances", mais c'est plus long).

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues: Selon ce que signifie *et réciproquement* dans la phrase originale, on peut considérer les deux options.

Comment: Ah, effectivement. Pour moi, le *et réciproquement* voulait dire "et qui, pour être intrinsèques et absolues, n'en sont pas moins aléatoires". Mais je ne suis pas sûr ce comprendre cette phrase de toute façon (j'ai pu la retrouver sur quelques forums, mais nulle part ailleurs).

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues: Oui, ce n'est pas une phrase très claire ;)